# Express.js & Node.js | Rendering template

Tags: html, node.js, express, template-engine

1) Can I render a view with Express without using any template file like jade?

I'm building a real-time chat system for Mobile Devs (cross-platform, so it's a web app) with Node, Express & Socket.io, and the server code core will be build for dispatch messages, user's requests & so on, I don't need to have a view but the result of the functions, because the view is already running on the device.

Comment: Yes, you can use EJS which looks like HTML with a few extra tokens to allow you to insert dynamic text.

Comment: Your question isn't clear : do you want to use a HTML file and no template (that's what my answer assumes) or do you want to use a template more like HTML (what @HectorCorrea seems to have understood) ?

Comment: I need to handle only the results of the functions without template or view. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really *rendering*, just *serving*.

You can send a file as answer using [res.sendfile](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile) :

```
res.sendfile("pathToYourFile.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send the results of functions, you can simply send the response without using a template by calling the `.end()` method ([documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding)) of the `response` object that Node passes. An example:

```js
function onRequest( request, response ) {
  functionResult = someFunctionYouWantToCall();
  response.end( functionResult );
}
```